# Plugin to Import Dropbox Files into Media Folder from the Cloud

Tags: uploads, media-library, cloud

I have been reading about options to use Dropbox as your upload folder and moving files to Dropbox from your server to put them in the cloud this way.

What I need is a plugin or script to move images from a Dropbox folder to my WordPress' server. This would save me a lot of time as the server is in Europe and I am now located in Asia. There are no such available plugins to my knowledge so one will have to be created.

I have found a [script](http://fabi.me/en/php-projects/dropphp-dropbox-api-client/) I am trying to work with to make this possible. It is one made by Fabi to download and upload files from a Dropbox account to your webserver.

I am just not sure yet on the approach I should go for. I could create a [plugin options page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) where you can enter Dropbox data and allow the upload to happen I guess. Never have gone this far in my development though. This will be my first plugin so tips would be welcome.

Second is the Dropbox API. It seems I will have to create a Dropbox app here https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps as well to make the plugin work with Dropbox using OAuth.

Other option would be to run the script as is form the server perhaps and make the necessary adjustments using the sample.php file, but the former idea seems cooler.

Is there anybody who has worked with the Dropbox api and plugins a lot who could give me some tips or who perhaps has snippets that could be of use? Thanks in advance.

Will see what I can achieve in the days ahead and leave updates when I can.

Comment: Your question is interesting and now much better than before. But it is still very broad. Asking for some tips or snippets makes it impossible to give a complete answer. I suggest you just start to write that plugin — it is a nice project to learn. Dropbox offers a [PHP SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php) that you can use. When you run into specific problems, like validating the options page data or storing the credentials, ask specific questions, and we can help you.

Comment: you can try [uploadcare](http://wordpress.org/plugins/uploadcare/) for this

Comment: How about http://www.wpallimport.com WP All Import is a good plugin and would work well for this.  You can use the dropbok image URL link, followed by the ?raw=1 suffix to grab individual images into your WP pages and posts.

Comment: I've created a plugin that might solve this issue: https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-media/ It is free and it doesn't use any file management services.